# How to cache in ASPNET Core with ResponseCache when the variance is in the route

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, caching

The ResponseCacheAttribute supports VaryByQueryKeys, which obviously creates a cache miss if the query string (or specified parts of the query string differ).

But, REST API design guidelines prefer the key of an HTTP GET to be in the route.

```
e.g.:
http://example.com/api/books/123
http://example.com/api/books/987
```

Whereas if you want to cache book 123 or 987 and vary the cache it would need to be?:

```
e.g.
http://example.com/api/books?id=123
http://example.com/api/books?id=987
```

I feel like I am missing something.  There is no "VaryByRoute" property of "ResponseCacheAttribute".

There are mentions of "vary-by-route" in classic ASPNET (not core)  I noticed headers of vary-by-route being used, but those are not directly appliable in ASP.NET core.

How should this be handled?
How do I vary the caching by the route where one of the parts of the route path is the "key"?

Comment: BTW, I had to indent everything (making it code) because it said there looks there is unformatted code.  Don't know if this is something new that it not working well?

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old and I hope you already had your answer, but this question appears in searches so I'll write a short one.

> Whereas if you want to cache book 123 or 987 and vary the cache it would need to be?:

No. Both paths goes to the same action method, where all query parameters (whether they are explicit or not) are paired with the ones on the method that are named.

So, assuming you have an action that can be simplified like this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
```

the ResponseCache attribute will works even if you omit the key name in the url path.